# InnoSetup - Set DefaultDirName at runtime

Tags: inno-setup

I have an application that needs to allow for up to three simultaneous installations on the same machine.

For some reason, the following code behaves as if UsePreviousAppDir is set to yes.  The second time I install the app, the path ends up mangled.

The value I want to see is

`C:\Our App\install_x` where x corresponds to the user's selection.

It works the first time, but the second run results in something like this:

`C:\Our App\install_x\install_y`, where x corresponds to the value selected with the first installation and y corresponds to the value selected during this installation.

The install version is a radio button selection grabbed from the first screen in the installer.  How do I eliminate this issue?

Setup section:

```
[Setup]
AppName=Our App
AppId=Our App
AppVerName=Our App Version(CM)
DefaultDirName=C:\Our App
DefaultGroupName=Our Group Name
OutputDir=..\
OutputBaseFilename=mm_setup
DisableStartupPrompt=yes
Compression=zip
UsePreviousAppDir=no
VersionInfoDescription=Our App Setup
CreateUninstallRegKey=no
DirExistsWarning=no
```

And the method where I set the install version:

```
procedure gSetVersion;
begin
  if gVersionPage.SelectedValueIndex = 0 then
  begin
     gInstallArea := 'install_a';
  end
  else if gVersionPage.SelectedValueIndex = 1 then
  begin
     gInstallArea := 'install_b';
  end
  else if gVersionPage.SelectedValueIndex = 2 then
  begin
     gInstallArea := 'install_c';
  end
  WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := WizardDirValue + '\' + gInstallArea;
end;
```

Comment: OT: you can simplify your `gSetVersion` procedure to [`this code`](http://pastebin.com/GBxKLdkz).

Comment: Thanks @TLama.  Any pointer on my main issue?

Comment: @StormeHawke The main problem seems to be connected with `UsePreviousAppDir=no` which should be `UsePreviousAppDir=False`. Additionally you could check `AppendDefaultDirName=False`.

Comment: @RobeN, the `AppendDefaultDirName` directive affects path only when you browse for folder, and [`UsePreviousAppDir`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_usepreviousappdir.htm) directive has values `yes` or `no`.

Comment: @TLama - well, I have just checked in Inno Script Studio and it says it should be `True` or `False`... Checked with dummy script and it works with `False` - probably IS Help is outdated at this point.

Comment: @RobeN this is the InnoSetup documentation for UsePreviousAppDir:
http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_delete.  Looks like it should be `no`

Comment: @StormeHawke - I know. Checked and it works both ways... Strange. Perhaps you could try `ExtractFileDir(ExpandConstant('{app}'))` which could slice `C:\Our App\install_x` to `C:\Our App`?

Comment: @RobeN, we're both right. To be [`more precise`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/CmnFunc2.pas#L1626), you can use `0`, `no` or `false` and because that string is compared by the [`CompareText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.SysUtils.CompareText) function, it's even case insensitive. But back to the problem, StormeHawke, I can't see anything wrong except the use of `WizardDirValue` variable. I would prefer to expand the value of `DefaultDirName` directive instead.

Comment: @TLama - checked and `WizardDirValue` sends (to MsgBox) `DefaultDirName` if `UsePreviousAppDir=no`.

Comment: @RobeN, that's why I wrote that I can't see anything wrong :-) It's not wrong to use `WizardDirValue`, I would just prefer a different way...

Comment: @StormeHawke - perhaps you could post whole code (with changed names of course) so that we could compile it on our side and test the result?

Comment: Unfortunately, the install script is pretty long and complicated and it's kind of frowned on to post huge code dumps on StackOverflow, plus I don't really want to go through and sanitize the whole file.  I did find a solution to the problem though... I hacked it by checking if the string "\install_" exists, truncating that off of the string, and then adding the install version back in

Comment: Note that if you're making it Uninstallable=no and UsePreviousAppDir=no due to the multi-install thing, that's the wrong thing to do.  All apps should ideally be uninstallable, especially side-by-side installs.  What you should do instead is to use `AppId={code:SomeAppIdCalculator}`.  See [the documentation](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_appid.htm) or ask a separate question for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem via the following hack.  Not sure why it was necessary to manually edit the string when the `UsePreviousAppDir=no' was set, but this works

```
procedure gSetVersion;
var
   installVersionIndex: Integer;
   installDir: String;
begin
  case gVersionPage.SelectedValueIndex of
    0: gInstallArea := 'install_a';
    1: gInstallArea := 'install_b';
    2: gInstallArea := 'install_c';
  end

  //Set the default installation folder.
  //This is necessary because InnoSetup intermittently
  //ignores the 'UsePreviousAppDir=no' [Setup] directive
  //and because the 'DefaultDirName' directive gets populated
  //prior to the user selecting the install version
  installVersionIndex := Pos('install_', WizardDirValue);
  installDir := WizardDirValue;
  if installVersionIndex > 0 then
  begin
    Delete(installDir, installVersionIndex, 20); 
  end

  WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := installDir + '\' + gInstallArea;
end;
```

Comment: Better define a constant for that directive. You can simply maintain it on one place and emit it value inside of your script. Look at [`this script`](http://pastebin.com/ZMazzD6M) for instance.